# I am having difficulties getting data from an associative model's parent model in Django

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I am building an app for a charity organization that performs service projects. Users click sign up buttons for corresponding projects and are redirected to a page that displays other users enrolled in particular projects 
[here is an image of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4bfW.png).
The problem is I can only display project participants by id when I want to list them by first and last name.

```
# models.py
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD  = 'email'
    chapter = models.ForeignKey('Club_Chapter',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = UserManager()

# Projects Availabe for Certain Clubs """
class Service_Project(models.Model):
    project_ID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    club_chapter = models.ForeignKey('Club_Chapter',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    project_title = models.CharField(max_length=15, help_text='Enter field documentation')
    project_location = models.CharField(max_length=15, help_text='Enter field documentation')

# Model where project sign up data is stored
class ProjectRegistration(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Service_Project, verbose_name='Project',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='volunteers', verbose_name='Worker',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    time_registered = models.DateTimeField()
    service_hrs = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

```
# views.py
class ExtraContextMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ExtraContextMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update(self.extra())
        return context

    def extra(self):
        return dict()


class DetailView(ExtraContextMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Service_Project
    template_name = 'catalog/detail.html'
    def extra(self):
        extra = ProjectRegistration.objects.all()
        return dict(extra = extra)
```

```
<!-- detail.html -->
{% for i in extra %}
  {% if extra and service_project.project_ID == i.project_id %}
     <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          USER_ID: {{i.user_id}}
          <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">Registered: {{i.time_registered}}</span>
        </li>
     </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Please let me know if my question or code is unclear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **dots** to access `user` attributes; So for example:

```
{{ i.user.first_name }}
```

and as well for other fields like `email`, `chapter`, etc.

#### Edit

I'm wondering why you are overriding the `get_context_data` as a mixin? Why you don't include it in your `DetailView`?

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Service_Project
    template_name = 'catalog/detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ExtraContextMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['extra'] = ProjectRegistration.objects.all()
        return context
```

Comment: I wish it were that simple but, since the class ExtraContentMixin maps to the model ProjectRegistration so I can only access fields from that class. Let me know if you need more information from urls.py, views.py, ect.

Comment: Mmm... So isn't `user` a field of `ProjectRegistration` class? also please check the edit; I think you can simplify your implementation.

Comment: I see what you're saying now, your implementation works much better. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? If so, please mark the answer as accepted so that other people can reference that later.